# How do I use '#' to be a column name in SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to declare a table which has a column name 'A#'

but # is the comment notation in sql,

I have tried 'A#' , '[A#]' ,but it's still not work.

Is it available to use # in column name?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I want to use in MySQL

Comment: Please remove the tag for SQL Server then.

Comment: Just don't. That would be best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
select `A#` from table;
```